# configure Pycharm to debug Odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, pycharm, odoo-8

i've installed pycharm community edition 2016.

I tried to configure it to debug Odoo as illustrated in the capture

[image]

When i open a python file set a breakpoint and click debug icon i got an exception:

[image]

Also  openerp, fields, api are underlined in red.

Any suggestions please. I use windows 8.1 as OS

**Update**:

According to Mariusz Answer , i'm now able to clic on debug bouton without any error.

Now i have put a brekpoint on a code to follow the execution, but the breakpoint is never reached ( the code is inside a buton method) while the method is executed. I can see the result in odoo page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First question - you are not supposed to run it from exe file, but from openerp-server, which is located in odoo installation folder via python interpreter. What is more, your configuration is wrong, because Odoo does not work with Python 3.4.1
My configuration looks like this:
[image]
Second question - you need to add your sources folder in Project Structure configuration so it is recognized by PyCharm as a folder from which to import.

Comment: You meant that Odoo doesn't work with Python 3.4.1? ;-)

Comment: hi @Mizgier, i don't have Openerp-server in Odoo installation but server instead. In script i added C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20150408\server . Also i already have source folder in project structure. Now i hit debug i got Permission denied. Pycharm is runing with admin role

Comment: @CZoellner Yes, i meant that it won't work with 3.4.1
OumarDiarra You have to download sources from https://github.com/odoo/odoo to run Odoo via PyCharm and not all-in-one package for it to work.

Comment: thank you @MariuszMizgier. Now i don't have any error. But seems that i cannot reach a breakpoint. I've updated my question. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To be able to reach breakpoint you have to disable gevent. At the moment of writing you can do it by commenting this piece of code in [openerp/__init__.py](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0.0/openerp/__init__.py#L28)

```py
import sys
evented = False
#if sys.modules.get("gevent") is not None:
#    evented = True
```

Comment: Disabled but still doesn't reach.

Comment: @OumarDiarra that sounds odd... can you confirm that code that you are trying to debug is reachable? (for example make a log after place where you made a breakpoint).

Comment: Yes it reachable. I added a print after the breakpoint and i'm able to see it in windows prompt command.